# Terraria monster banners

Tags: terraria-mobile

Do monster banners drop in Android Terraria? I have mined nearly my entire first world, killed a few bosses, and I haven't seen a single one. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only assume that banners do not exist in the mobile version of the game.
The [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Monster_Banner) on Banners (Monster Banners) tags it only as "PC Content" and "Console Content".

Were they in the Mobile Version, there would be a "Mobile Content" tag.

Comment: If it had a mobile counterpart I doubt it would have ANY tags as it would apply to all up-to-date versions.

Answer (score -1):

They do but its a rare drop. So basicly you have a little mob spawner with a bunch of water candles an sometimes you'll get a banner.

Comment: While we don't mind conflicting answers do you have evidence to support your own?

Comment: @Vanguard66 ahhhh, i thought by "tag" the accepted answer was referring to the console tag which appears on some banners